# jQuery Toggle modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I am using the below javascript (jQuery) to toggle open two DIVs.  The DIVs open fine and open one at a time, which is what I am after.  However, I also want the DIVs to close when they are clicked a second time, which doesn't happen despite my best efforts!

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.info_tab').click( function() {
        var currentID = $(this).next().attr("id");
        $('.toggle_info[id!=currentID]').hide(); /* the intention here is to hide anything that is not the current toggling DIV so as to close them as a new one is opened.  I thought this would leave the currently selected DIV uninterrupted to toggle closed (below), but it doesn't */
        $(this).next().toggle();
        return false;
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="info_tab">
            <h1>Person One</h1><br />
            <p>click for less info</p>
        </div>
        <div id="person_one_info" class="toggle_info">
            <p>More information about Philip Grover</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info_tab">
            <h1>Person Two</h1><br />
            <p>click for less info</p>
        </div>
        <div id="person_two_info class="toggle_info">
            <p>More information about Roy Lewis</p>
        </div>
```

If any more info is needed, just ask and I'll be happy to edit the question.

Cheers,

Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have the concept down, but not using the "currentID" correctly. You need to remember it's a variable, and can't be in another string if you want it evaluated.

With that said, try this:

```
$('.toggle_info[id!='+currentID+']').hide();
```

This makes the variable get evaluated in the selector, then passes it off to jQuery to find.

it looks like you're going to an accordian effect though. And jQuery UI has [just such a control](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) that you can use (if you're interested). if you're going for experience, then carry on. ;-)

Comment: Works Perfectly! I was just going for experience - my last gasp was using jQuery's accordion but I was sure I could do it myself! Thanks very much :)

Comment: @richieahb: Kudos to you then. here's a demo if you'd like, just to confirm. also made it slide instead of just hide/show. ;-) http://www.jsfiddle.net/3VuAK/